# How to dump dynamic loaded page via Apache as static HTML page

Tags: javascript, php, html, linux, apache

I have a PHP driven website. That System is using Linux OS. I want to dump homepage of website as HTML, css and JS files only (so that it can be viewd without PHP webserver). Is there any option via webserver (Apache) or any other tool so that I should get exactly page what is shown via PHP. Actually, I have to place that HTML page some where else for demo purpose.

Comment: in the browser, you only have html code... i don't get where you are going with this? what's the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want HTML version of page loaded in browser. I have to automate it via bash also.

Comment: You can use wget to create a mirror of the website e.g: wget -mk http://website.com

Comment: Maybe this will be useful (if you want it self-contained): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mhtml